# "Package nameofthepackage does not exist"

Tags: java

I am trying to make a jar file in intelliJ. My directory that holds all the java classes is C:\trafficProject\src\cege. In cege there is a package ui where there is a class GuiMain. And I have imported the GuiMain() in my Main() class.

I have this code lines:

package cege;

import cege.ui.GuiMain;

and when I use the terminal in the intelliJ and write the command:

C:\trafficProject\src\cege>javac *.java

I get this message:

Main.java:3: error: package cege.ui does not exist
import cege.ui.GuiMain;

but actually, I have already put this line in my code. This confuses me.

Can anybody help me what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set your `classpath`?

Comment: Try calling `javac` from the `src` folder. You should read about the [java compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javac/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the base directory of the package in the classpath. That is the directory `C:\trafficProject\src` in your case.

If you do not have the `CLASSPATH` environment variable set and you don't specify the classpath explicitly to the `javac` command, then the current directory `.` will be used as the default classpath.

That means you should compile and run your code from `C:\trafficProject\src`, like this:

```
C:\trafficProject\src> javac cege\*.java

C:\trafficProject\src> java cege.Main
```

Note: the `java` command, to run a Java program, takes a class name, such as `cege.Main`, not a filename.

Comment: I would like to ask you kindly to help me with this now. I have all this code but I get a message at the end that could not find or load the Main class.                                       C:\trafficProject\src>echo Main-Class: Main >manifest.txt     

C:\trafficProject\src>jar cvfm trafficProject.jar manifest.txt     
added manifest

C:\trafficProject\src>java -jar trafficProject.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class Main

Comment: Your main class is called `cege.Main`, not `Main`. So you should put `cege.Main` in the manifest file, not just `Main`. See [Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)